# PDF long text extraction to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, pdf

I'm trying to create a python script that extracts text from a PDF then converts it to a correctly formatted JSON file (see below).

The text extraction is not a problem. I'm using PyPDF2 to extract the text from user inputted pdf - which will often result in a LONG text string. I would like to add this text as a 'value' to a json 'key' (see 2nd example below).

My code:

```
# Writing all data to JSON file

# Data to be written 
dictionary ={ 
  "company": str(company), 
  "document": str(document), 
  "text": str(text) # This is what would be a LONG string of text
} 
      
# Serializing json  
json_object = json.dumps(dictionary, indent = 4) 
print(json_object)

with open('company_document.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(json_object, fp)
```

The ideal output would be a JSON file that is structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "company": 1,
    "document-name": "Orlando",
    "text": " **LONG_TEXT_HERE** "
  }
]
```

I'm not getting the right json structure as an output. Also, the long text string most likely contains some punctuation or special characters that can affect the json - such as closing the string too early. I could take this out before, but is there a way to keep it in for the json file so I can address it in the next step (in Neo4j) ?

This is my output at the moment:

```
"{\n    \"company\": \"Stack\",\n    \"document\": \"Overflow Report\",\n    \"text\": \"Long text 2020\\nSharing relevant and accountable information about our development "quotes and things...
```

Current:
[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvd4X.png)

Goal:
[Ideal situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUBz7.png)

Does anyone have an idea on how this can be achieved?

Comment: What you have in your example is a LIST of objects, not just an object.  Have you tried `json.dumps([dictionary])`?  And you should not do `json.dump` on the output of `json.dumps`.  Your last line should be `json.dump([dictionary], fp)`.  And `json.dumps` is perfectly capable of handling special characters.

Comment: Thank you, I added the [ ] around dictionary in the 11th line (that should work the same, yes?) and it improved the output but it's still not the correct format and the quotation marks in the pdf extracted text seem to break the JSON value formatting. I just added some pictures so you can see more clearly what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Like many people, you are confusing the CONTENT of your data with the REPRESENTATION of your data.  The code you have works just fine.  Notice:

```
import json

# Data to be written 
dictionary ={ 
  "company": 1,
  "document": "Orlando",
  "text": """Long text 2020
Sharing relevant and accountable information about our development.
This is a complicated text string with "quotes and things".
"""
} 


# Serializing json  
json_object = json.dumps([dictionary], indent = 4) 
print(json_object)

with open('company_document.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump([dictionary], fp)
```

When executed, this produces the following on stdout:

```
[
    {
        "company": 1,
        "document": "Orlando",
        "text": "Long text 2020\nSharing relevant and accountable information about our development.\nThis is a complicated text string with \"quotes and things\".\n"
    }
]
```

Notice that the embedded quotes are escaped.  That's what the standard requires.  The file does not have the indentation, because you didn't ask for it, but it's still quite valid JSON.

```
[{"company": 1, "document": "Orlando", "text": "Long text 2020\nSharing relevant and accountable information about our development.\nThis is a complicated text string with \"quotes and things\".\n"}]
```

### FOLLOWUP

This version reads in whatever was in the file before, adds a new record to the list, and saves the whole thing out.

```
import os
import json

# Read existing data.

MASTER = "company_document.json"
if os.path.exists( MASTER ):
    database = json.load( open(MASTER,'r') )
else:
    database = []

# Data to be written 
dictionary ={ 
  "company": 1,
  "document": "Orlando",
  "text": """Long text 2020
Sharing relevant and accountable information about our development.
This is a complicated text string with "quotes and things".
"""
} 

# Serializing json  
json_object = json.dumps([dictionary], indent = 4) 
print(json_object)

database.append(dictionary)
with open(MASTER, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(database, fp)
```

Comment: Hi @Tim Roberts - thank you. I understand that the above in your response is correct, however, I'm getting the following: "|{\n    \"company\": \"Stack\",\n    \"document\": \"Overflow Report\",\n    \"text\": \"Long text............."}] as my output when viewing the file as a JSON. Will this still work to retreive values from keys in other programs / code ? i would have thought the \n etc would not be viewable - because it seems like they're now part of the string

Comment: If that's what is stored in the file, then you are still using `json.dump` on the output of `json.dumps`, thereby doing double-encoding.  You either write the result of the `dumps` directly (e.g.,  `fp.write(json_object)`), or you pass the original `[dictionary]` to `json.dump`.

Comment: Thank you @Tim - how might I save the output json file so it doesn't overwrite or append to previous outputs? I'm thinking of taking the user input for 'document' as the filename - but drawing blanks

Comment: What other choice is there besides "overwrite" or "append"?  ;)  You can't just append to a JSON file.  Are you saying that file has other companies that you need to retain?  You certainly didn't make that clear in the problem description.

Comment: Hey again @Tim - I originally had an 'output.json' file and my second run through the script with a different pdf file became appended to the first one. Maybe it was slightly different code at that point - but no, I want each json file to contain info about one company only. And the file should never overwrite previous output files or append to the previous file. I would like to name each file based on the user inputted 'document type' text to prevent this - but I'm at a loss how to do that

Comment: What do you mean by "at a loss"?  A file name is just a string.  If you have a document type, then you can create your string based on that, and use it in the `with(open(...))`.  Right?  This is not hard.

Comment: I get your point - creating a filename from a string isn't difficult. perhaps I'm not clarifying my considerations, such as user inputting characters that are not valid filenames or adding a conversion for user inputs that might be invalid.

Comment: Those are good considerations.  You can go through the input string, and throw out anything that's not in your desired set.  That's a short function to write.